# Node-red node icons meaning and purpose?

Tags: editor, node-red

I'm new to node-red running on my Raspberry Pi 3 and have search with no luck for an explanation for the different icons, in the node-red editor, on some built-in nodes, for example the mqtt node. What is the meaning and purpose of the red and blue icons on this node?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Blue dot indicates that the node has undeployed changes

The Red triangle means that node is either missing required configuration data or has some configuration data that does not validate